# using Ajax for partial view loading in .NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to follow the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848219/how-to-call-partial-views-ajax-based-directly-on-index-page-of-a-view-mvc-wi), which may very well be wrong, to learn a little more about partial view loading in MVC. I know the basics of MVC but want to do more of the ajax stuff I used to do before I started using MVC.

**The goal is to have the partial view load INSIDE the div.** Its just loading the partial view as the whole page, rather than inside of the Div.

Code is as follows:

Controller:

```
namespace LDP.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Test/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public PartialViewResult Page1()
        {
            return PartialView("Page1");
        }
        public PartialViewResult Page2()
        {
            return PartialView("Page2");
        }
    }
}
```

Main View (Index): (I also tried "mainDiv" without the pound sign, wasen't sure which was right)

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/libs/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#hideme').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Parial Page1", "Page1", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mainDiv"})
@Ajax.ActionLink("Parial Page2", "Page2", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mainDiv"})
<div id ='mainDiv'>

</div>
<button id ="hideme">Hide Me</button>
</div>
```

Partial View 1 (Page1.cshtml)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page1";
}

<h2>Page1</h2>
```

Partial View 2 (Page2.cshtml)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page2";
}

<h2>Page2</h2>
```

Update:
I created a brand new MVC 4 project. This comes, by default, with Jquery 1.7.1 and the unobtrusive-ajax library from microsoft. It still loads the partial view in a new page...

Update: Not sure if this helps, but the following does achieve the result I want... But still doesn't solve the problem as to why this solution doesn't work

```
<button>load about</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#mainDiv").load("Test/Page2");
    });

</script>
    enter code here
```

Comment: Have you tried by setting Layout = null in partial view ?

Comment: how do you set layout = null?

Comment: @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page2";
    Layout = nulll;
}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. ditch `#` in `UpdateTargetId = "#mainDiv"`
2. make sure you have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` script referenced on your page.

Comment: Is this jquery file not included in the full jquery library? I'm including 1.8.2, do I need to get this file seperatly?

Comment: it's not included. You can [download it](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js) from Microsoft though.

Comment: OK i have it downloaded and included. I can sucessfully use a jquery function, but the it's still not loading the page1 and page2 inside the div... ideas?

Comment: is there any run time errors? If you don't see any, you should try using Fiddler to see response in details

Comment: There is an error showing up "Sys is not defined" I don't have a variable called sys though...

Answer (score 13):

I copied your code into a brand new MVC4 project and it works fine.

See screenshot of the solution:

[image: Brand new MVC4 project with Ajax.ActionLink]

Hope this will give you a hint on what could be wrong.

Comment: ya, so the past day or two I have been messing around with this test project testing a few POC with MVC and now I go back and try this feature and it works. I have no idea what I did to make it work. I sware it didn't work before... :/ But thanks for your help! Hopefully someone else can get value out of this post too

Comment: works for me.  This is great for passing parameters without displaying in URL!

Answer (score 4):

I typically load partials like this using JQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $("#lnkPage1").click(function( event ) {

    $('#mainDiv').load('Test/Pag1');

  });

  $("#lnkPage2").click(function( event ) {

    $('#mainDiv').load('Test/Pag2');

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxViewCall", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))   
{
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Ajax Form Action" />
    </p>
}

<div id="result></div>
```

On the button click it should call the Action that returns a PartialView. You dont need the '#' in your Ajax.BeginForm call.

Comment: this produces the same result. The page shows up on a new page rather than in the result div.

Answer (score 0):

Only issue I had with original example was the \lib\ in script src path.  Default MVC 4 Web app will put js files in "Scripts", not "Scripts\Lib". Your screen shot example is correct.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"
```

Also in the original example - putting in ViewBag.Title will cause this to not work:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Some Title";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same issue; loading the partial view as the whole page rather than in the defined div.

I was incorrectly presuming that my `_Layout.cshtml` was including the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file as I didn't understand what the Bundles thingy(?) was doing. I thought it was being added by Bundles.

In my `_Layout.cshtml` View it defines `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`
Which in English is; it's optional to include a section in your view called @scripts.
So no error is thrown if you don't include it (@section scripts) but the symptom is that the Ajax just renders in a new page if you don't.

To fix it: put the following in your view (I put it below the `...ViewBag.Title; }`)

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
}
```

Sorry if my explanation is a bit rudimentary, I'm a bit new to this. Hoping this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

load json data or table partial view. not full format view.

```
success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    debugger;
    ('#div_id').data(data);
}
```

here, returned data is json data or data like

data

.
use alert to check the data.