# refresh only a sidebar that contains pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have a web page that contains a sidebar where i show data with Pagination using PagedList.

so i want go to the next page or the previous without refreshing all the page, just the sidebar where i have the Pagination.
so here's the code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, string currentFilter, int? page)
 {

  IEnumerable<CheckpointsModel> checkpoints = (from ch in dbcontext.checkPoint select new CheckpointsModel { checkpointID = ch.checkpointsid, adress = ch.city, lattitude = ch.lattitude, longidue = ch.longitude, indice = ch.id }).ToList();       
        IEnumerable<AlertsModel> alerts = (from al in dbcontext.Alert where(al.isReported=="No") select new AlertsModel { cinDr = al.cinDr, permitNumber = al.permitNumDr, name = al.nameDr, Drpicture = al.pictureDr, cinOw = al.cinOw, OwpermitNumber = al.PermitNumOw, Owname = al.nameOw, Owpicture = al.pictureOw, carNumber = al.carNum, brand = al.brand, model = al.model, carpicture = al.carPicture, alertType = al.alertType, lattitude = al.lattitude, longitude = al.longitude, speed = al.carSpeed }).ToList();



        var AlertsCheckpoints = new AlertViewModel
            {
                alerts=alerts,
                checkpoints=checkpoints
            };
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }
        else
        {
            page = 1;
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "cin":
                AlertsCheckpoints.alerts = AlertsCheckpoints.alerts.OrderByDescending(s => s.cinOw);
                break;
            case "Prenom":
                AlertsCheckpoints.alerts = AlertsCheckpoints.alerts.OrderBy(s => s.Owname);
                break;
            default:

                AlertsCheckpoints.alerts = AlertsCheckpoints.alerts.OrderBy(s => s.Owname);
                break;
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "City":
                AlertsCheckpoints.checkpoints = AlertsCheckpoints.checkpoints.OrderByDescending(s => s.adress);
                break;
            case "ID":
                AlertsCheckpoints.checkpoints = AlertsCheckpoints.checkpoints.OrderBy(s => s.checkpointID);
                break;
            default:
                AlertsCheckpoints.checkpoints = AlertsCheckpoints.checkpoints.OrderBy(s => s.checkpointID);
                break;
        }
        int pageSize = 1;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var paginatedmodel = new AlertViewModel(alerts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize), checkpoints.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        return View(paginatedmodel);
    }
```

and here's my View(index):

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Map.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
         @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
            }
        @{
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithSidebar.cshtml";
        }
<td><label>Page @(Model.alerts.PageCount < Model.alerts.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.alerts.PageNumber)
    of @(Model.alerts.PageCount) </label></td>
@section Sidebar {

 @foreach (var al in Model.alerts)
 { 

<table border="0">
<tr>
<td rowspan=1 class="alert-type"><label class="label" style="font-size:0.85em;">Alert type  :</label></td>
<td><label class="label" style="font-size:0.85em;"> @Html.Raw(al.alertType)</label></td>

</table>

    <hr />
<br />
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td rowspan=3><img src= '@Html.Raw(al.Drpicture)' class="img" alt="IMAGES"/></td>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.cinDr)</label></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.name)</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.permitNumber)</label></td>

</tr>

</table>
<br />
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td rowspan=4><img src= '@Html.Raw(al.carpicture)' class="img" alt="IMAGES"/></td>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.carNumber)</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.brand)</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.model)</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.speed)</label></td>
</tr>
</table> 
<br />
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td rowspan=3><img src= '@Html.Raw(al.Owpicture)' class="img" alt="IMAGES"/></td>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.cinOw)</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.Owname)</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label class="lb">@Html.Raw(al.OwpermitNumber)</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
     <div>


    @if (Model.alerts.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.alerts.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev
    }

    @if (Model.alerts.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.alerts.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.alerts.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    }
    else
    {
        @:Next >
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @:>>
    }
</div>
        <script>
            var lat = '@Html.Raw(al.lattitude)';
            var lng = '@Html.Raw(al.longitude)';
            var carNum = '@Html.Raw(al.carNumber)';
        </script>
        <input type="submit" name="CheckPoints" value="CheckPoints" onclick="getMap(places, lat, lng)" />
        <input type="submit" name="Tracking" value="Tracking" data-coords="coords()" data-att="@al.lattitude" data-lng="@al.longitude"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Report" value="Report" data-carnum="@al.carNumber" />
            }
             }
```

so Please can anyone help me here. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about ajax and partial views. 
Here is an example of how to do it:

[using Ajax for partial view loading in .NET MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529936/using-ajax-for-partial-view-loading-in-net-mvc4)

and here is a tutorial you can use. It says its for mvc3 but you can apply the same to MVC4

http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx