# Controller calling itself and passing a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to pass data from the controller to itself?

Consider this example:

I have a page that consists of two parts: (1) a simple html form with a couple of text boxes and a submit button and (2) a table that is updated when the button from part (1) is pressed. When it happens, the data from the form has to be appended to the end of the table.
As I see it, there should exist a `List` of objects. Every time the button is pressed, the controller is called with two parameters: the old list of objects and textbox values. Then, the controller generates the object, adds it to the list and passes the new list to the view. The view is rendered with the new data and rows are successfully added to the table.
However, that requires reloading of the page and that feels kinda wrong.

The problem is, that there is no static object that can contain the list permanently, or at least that exists during these controller-self-calls. If there was such, I would not have to pass the whole list (which, as I said, I can't even do) but just new textbox values.
I have heard that partial views can solve the problem, but I can't see how.

What can I do?

Comment: Can't you use client side to add rows to part 2 without going to server side?

Comment: Yes, this is easily achievable with JavaScript, but since I'm learning ASP.NET MVC, I want to use it's features, if possible.

Comment: Where is the controller self-call? I only see one HTTP POST call which returns a View. Thats Client > Server > Client. where's the Server > Server-call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, as you said you'd like to achieve this without javascript, I see no way of avoiding: `reloading of the page and that feels kinda wrong.`

Not sure as well how partial views will make things work since they're rendered from your main view and require the same or part of your model, so you'll need to have that data there.

You have to get the information back from the controller, and the controller must get this information somehow so as I see it, these are your options:

1. **Keep part (2) inside your form**, thus making both parts available when you hit the controller. Model will get populated with the values you need and then the data is available for you when you're back at the View.
2. **Keep a hidden input field** inside part (1) containing the data you require to create the list. It's similar in concept to option #1 but I don't like this method too much, you'll have to do some parsing on that input field and this is not very elegant.

You could also try use `Session` or database but I think the latter is an overkill and a hit on performance so I wouldn't go with that.

Comment: So which option is the good one? Or is it about different kinds of bad?
First and second options are clumsy, database is heavy. Is there no "right" way to do it?

Also, thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze The right answer to me is to use javascript :) I've had to use both solutions myself, depending on the situation. If your goal is to learn, then why not just try all to get the experience. If this is also applicable and you can go with Session, I'll go with Session.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a database backing the form data, you could use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) data to hold the List.

In the controller, do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToList(object newObject) 
{

    var list = Sesssion["List"] as List<Object>;
    if (list == null) { 
        list = new List<Object>();
        Session["List"] = list;
    }
    list.add(newObject);
    return View(list); // Assuming the view is a strong-typed view with List<Object> as model
}
```

As for partial views, they do not alone solve the problem of reloading the page. The solve the problem of a reusable, self-containing component of the page. If you don't like the reload of the page, you can use partial views together with Ajax calls though, in order to refetch the table whenever a new item is added. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529936/using-ajax-for-partial-view-loading-in-net-mvc4)

Comment: Thank you for the possible solution and example code.